# Python xml change a attribute value by sorting on grandgrandparent attribute

Tags: python, xml

I'm new to coding and python so I thank you all in advance for have a little extra patient with me :)

So, here is my problem:
I'm trying to code a python script that changes an attribute called z_neg (in < motions >), if(!) its grandgrandparents attribute is containing the attribute name='x-stiff' (in <line_support>). Moreover, I want the script to change all the z_neg attributes in  for all <line_support> that have the attribute name containing 'x-stiff'. I fail right now in sorting out the grandgrandparent.

Best regards,
Emil

I have tried some different ways with for loops and can't get further than either finding all <line_support> or < motions>, and here are my latest attempts:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et 
et.register_namespace('', 'urn:strusoft')
model_path = '\\FEM\\floor1\\model_1.struxml'

tree = et.parse(model_path)
root = tree.getroot()
for support2 in root[0].iter("{urn:strusoft}motions"):
print(support2.tag, support2.attrib)
```

I have also tried similarly ways like:

```
for support in root.findall(".//motions/../../../[@name='x-stiff']/"):
 print(support.attrib)
```

but fails :)
XML code:

```
<database xmlns="urn:strusoft" struxml_version="01.00.000" source_software="FEM-Design 22.00.001" start_time="1970-01-01T00:00:00.000" end_time="2023-03-17T10:21:10.000" guid="e2686f2d-4156-4971-8d86-5ef16a5c2169" convertid="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" standard="EC" country="S">
    <entities>
        <supports>
            <line_support guid="22938a5b-b5f2-48b0-8ab0-182dfcad415e" last_change="2023-03-16T13:13:57.000" action="added" name="S.1">
                <group>
                    <local_x x="1" y="2.58195798774967E-12" z="0" />
                    <local_y x="-2.58195798774967E-12" y="1" z="0" />
                    <rigidity>
                        <motions x_neg="0" x_pos="0" y_neg="0" y_pos="0" z_neg="5" z_pos="10000000" />
                        <rotations x_neg="0" x_pos="0" y_neg="0" y_pos="0" z_neg="0" z_pos="0" />
                    </rigidity>
                </group>
                <edge type="line">
                    <point x="24.6263818250883" y="-8.80836202657059" z="0" />
                    <point x="28.6628090737921" y="-8.80836202656017" z="0" />
                    <normal x="-2.58195798774967E-12" y="1" z="0" />
                </edge>
                <normal x="0" y="0" z="1" />
            </line_support>
            <line_support guid="d666b23d-df57-4f3d-b950-06fa4fc3227a" last_change="2023-03-16T13:14:12.000" action="added" name="S.2">
                <group>
                    <local_x x="0" y="-1" z="0" />
                    <local_y x="1" y="0" z="0" />
                    <rigidity>
                        <motions x_neg="0" x_pos="0" y_neg="0" y_pos="0" z_neg="5" z_pos="10000000" />
                        <rotations x_neg="0" x_pos="0" y_neg="0" y_pos="0" z_neg="0" z_pos="0" />
                    </rigidity>
                </group>
                <edge type="line">
                    <point x="28.6628090737918" y="-14.4898620056551" z="0" />
                    <point x="28.6628090737921" y="-19.081361992569" z="0" />
                    <normal x="1" y="0" z="0" />
                </edge>
                <normal x="0" y="0" z="1" />
            </line_support>
            <line_support guid="21cf4052-e4ba-414d-a7ee-c78ecef2a3ff" last_change="2023-03-17T10:20:54.000" action="added" name="x-stiff.1">
                <group>
                    <local_x x="1" y="0" z="0" />
                    <local_y x="0" y="1" z="0" />
                    <rigidity>
                        <motions x_neg="100000" x_pos="100000" y_neg="0" y_pos="0" z_neg="11" z_pos="10000000" />
                        <rotations x_neg="0" x_pos="0" y_neg="0" y_pos="0" z_neg="0" z_pos="0" />
                    </rigidity>
                </group>
                <edge type="line">
                    <point x="9.18988193734352" y="-12.244862026923" z="0" />
                    <point x="12.4263090828062" y="-12.2448620269228" z="0" />
                    <normal x="0" y="1" z="0" />
                </edge>
                <normal x="0" y="0" z="1" />
            </line_support>
            <line_support guid="c8d5eed1-302b-45b4-a943-0ad8202f2d78" last_change="2023-03-17T10:20:54.000" action="added" name="x-stiff.2">
                <group>
                    <local_x x="1" y="0" z="0" />
                    <local_y x="0" y="1" z="0" />
                    <rigidity>
                        <motions x_neg="100000" x_pos="100000" y_neg="0" y_pos="0" z_neg="5" z_pos="10000000" />
                        <rotations x_neg="0" x_pos="0" y_neg="0" y_pos="0" z_neg="0" z_pos="0" />
                    </rigidity>
                </group>
                <edge type="line">
                    <point x="22.1863819301654" y="-8.80836202657082" z="0" />
                    <point x="24.6263818250883" y="-8.80836202657059" z="0" />
                    <normal x="0" y="1" z="0" />
                </edge>
                <normal x="0" y="0" z="1" />
            </line_support>
            <line_support guid="c61c91cc-ef02-49bf-9b94-19df5db97e04" last_change="2023-03-17T10:20:54.000" action="added" name="x-stiff.3">
                <group>
                    <local_x x="1" y="0" z="0" />
                    <local_y x="0" y="1" z="0" />
                    <rigidity>
                        <motions x_neg="100000" x_pos="100000" y_neg="0" y_pos="0" z_neg="5" z_pos="10000000" />
                        <rotations x_neg="0" x_pos="0" y_neg="0" y_pos="0" z_neg="0" z_pos="0" />
                    </rigidity>
                </group>
                <edge type="line">
                    <point x="25.4263819283295" y="-12.244862026923" z="0" />
                    <point x="28.6628090737921" y="-12.2448620269228" z="0" />
                    <normal x="0" y="1" z="0" />
                </edge>
                <normal x="0" y="0" z="1" />
            </line_support>

        </supports>
    </entities>
    <end />
</database>
```

Comment: Are you looking for `name` attributes whose value is exactly "x-stiff" or attributes whose value contains the string "x-stiff" (such as "x-stiff.1")? I suspect it is the latter.

Comment: The latter is correct. And when found the string "x-stiff" I want it to change the value of subsubchild motions attribute "z_neg".

Comment: What should the updated `z_neg` values be?

Comment: The script is going to be used for a finite element model to adjust stiffness in z_neg direction, thus z_neg is going to be changed in a loop between two limits. ex startvalue of 5 and increment of 5 unitil it reaches 100.  (5,100,5)

Comment: Not sure I understand. If the current value is 11, should it be changed to 16?

Comment: ok, I tried to scale the whole coding down a bit in the question but backfired :), however, from the beginning:
The aim of the coding is to perform a loop that for each run changes the values of z_neg and z_pos with an arbitrary increment, the increment isn't chosen at this point, and ofc with a starting value and end value. Moreover, I do only wanna change the z_neg and z_pos for <line_support> elements with the attribute "name" containing "x-stiff". Hope this clear it out.

Comment: I have posted an answer that I hope is useful even if it does not do exactly what you want. It is not possible to cover every detail in a single answer. This question already has 13 revisions. `z_pos` is not even mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a code snippet that I hope can help. Here is what it does:

1. Find all the `line_support` elements.
2. For each `line_support` element with a `name` attribute that contains the string "x-stiff", locate the `motions` descendant.
3. On the `motions` element, change the value of the `z_neg` attribute.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

ET.register_namespace('', 'urn:strusoft')

tree = ET.parse("test.xml")   # The XML in the question

line_support_elems = tree.findall(".//{*}line_support")

for line_support in line_support_elems:
    name = line_support.get("name")
    if "x-stiff" in name:
        motions = line_support.find(".//{*}motions")
        motions.set("z_neg", "UPDATED")
```

Notes:

- Instead of writing out the full namespace name in `find()` and `findall()`, a `{*}` wildcard is used.
- It is not clear what the updated `z_neg` values should be, so I have just set them to "UPDATED".